# How to use ng-include with an html file in double curly brace notation {{ }}

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have the following code:

```
<div  ng-repeat="pTabs in child.productTabs" ng-click="toggleProductTab($index)" ng-if="productTabIsActive(pTabs, $index)">
    <div ng-repeat="specs in pTab.additionalSpecs">
        <p>{{specs.content}}</p>  <!--Displays url-->
        <div ng-include  src = {{specs.content}}></div>  <!--My attempt to display the html content-->
    </div>
</div>
```

`{{specs.content}}` is an html file containing the html I want to use on the page. When I wrap it in the `<p>` tag, the URL is displayed as text on my page. How can I add the html content to my page using ng-include? I've tried to changing the syntax up but nothing has worked thus far.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know, you didn't have to use the curly braces notation inside an angular directive. Use `ng-include src = specs.content`

Answer (score 3):

the src is an angular directive part of the ng-include and does not need curly braces, you can do

A) `<div ng-include src="scopeObj.prop">` in case of having the string name of the html file stored in a scope variable or object;

B) `<div ng-include src="'template.html'">` in case of inserting the string directly in your html code (note the double and single quotes)

also in case that you need to insert HTML in your code by using curly braces youll notice that by default angular convert any html entity in its text representarion, for that you can use

A) `<div ng-bind-html="scopeObj.var">` also the quote doble quote method should work for that

B) if you really want to use curly braces to insert html (and its highly recomendable that you dont or use only when youre sure your html is safe) you need to do the following:

- Import angular-sanitize module to your project and inject the 'ngSanitize' to your angular module

  - Create a filter like this:

  .filter('unsafe',function ($sce) {
      return function (val) {
          return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
      };
  })

  - and then in your html code

  {{ scopeObj.var | unsafe }}

Answer (score 1):

Its simple as shown below. You are almost there.

```
<div  ng-repeat="pTabs in child.productTabs" ng-click="toggleProductTab($index)" ng-if="productTabIsActive(pTabs, $index)">
        <div ng-repeat="specs in pTab.additionalSpecs">
            <p>{{specs.content}}</p>  <!--Displays url-->
            <div ng-include  src = "{{specs.content}}"></div> 

           // My ans- here I'm using  src="{{specs.content}}". Note: I'm wrapping curly braces by quotes. I assume specs.content gets required template path. eg. $scope.specs.content='templates/index.html';
        </div>
    </div>
```

let me know if doesn't work.